# FLEX replace words with dates

Tags: c++, flex-lexer

Im really new to flex and sadly there are very few examples on the internet compared to other languages.
I want to replace the words:

1. TODAY with today's date
2. TOMORROW with tomorrows date1
3. YESTERDAY with yesterdays date
4. TODAY-n with todays date before n days
5. TODAY+n with todays date after n days.

I did some research and the only thing i find is replace just 1 word with another word in a string. which is totally different.

Just some progress i made:

```
TODAY "TODAY"
YESTERDAY "YESTERDAY"
TOMORROW "TOMORROW"
TODAY+n "TODAY+n"
TODAY-n "TODAY-n"

%%
{TODAY} {op=1;}
{YESTERDAY} {op=2;}
{TOMORROW} {op=3;}
{TODAY+n} {op=4;}
{TODAY-n} {op=5;}
%%

date()
{
    if (op==0)
    
    a=(yytext);
    
    switch(op)
    {
        case 1:TODAY;
        break;
        
        case 2:YESTERDAY;
        break;
        
        case 3:TOMORROW;
        break;
        
        case 4;TODAY+n;
        break;
        
        case 5;TODAY-n;
        break;
    }
    op=0;
}
```

Comment: It is clear that there are several things that you don't understand yet, so it is not easy to answer your question. [Here](http://xahlee.info/parser/lex_tutorial.html) you have a useful minimalistic tutorial on Flex, I hope it helps you. Also, have a look at the [ctime](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/) library, you might find it useful.

Comment: The [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/) starts with a good introduction as well. Although the best learning resource is probably still John Levine's book on Flex and Bison, published by O'Reilly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very basic implementation, concentrating on flex rather than the intricacies of computing and showing dates. It depends on the fact that the default action for unrecognised characters is to copy them to the output stream. However, to avoid recognising `TODAY` in the middle of a word (like `AATODAYBB`), I added a pattern which matches any word consisting only of alphabetic characters and copies it to the output stream explicitly (using `ECHO`). Depending on your actual needs, you might want to adjust that.

A quick read of the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/) should be sufficient to understand the program. In particular, take a look at the introductory material, including simple examples; the description of patterns (which is similar but not identical to standard regular expressions, but missing a lot of costly features like captures); and the description of the way the input is scanned. That last section also explains the so-called "maximal munch" (first longest match) algorithm which is used here in the last rule (which must be the last rule).

```
%option noinput nounput noyywrap
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    /* Replace this with a function which actually shows the correct date */
    void show_date(int offset) {
      if (offset > 0)
        fprintf(yyout, "<today's date + %d>", offset);
      else
        fprintf(yyout, "<today's date %.0d>", offset);
    }
%}

%%
TODAY           { show_date(0); }
TOMORROW        { show_date(1); }
YESTERDAY       { show_date(-1); }
TODAY[+-][0-9]+ { show_date(atoi(yytext + 5)); /* +5 to skip TODAY */ }
[[:alpha:]]+    { ECHO; /* Avoid false matches. See text. */ }
```

To compile and run:

```
# (Assuming the above file is called date_subst.l)
flex -o date_subst.c date_subst.l
gcc -Wall -g -o date_subst date_subst.c -lfl
./date_subst
```